# PHP - divide two values

Tags: php, json

I'm having problem on dividing two values and it keeps showing

> Warning: Division by zero in ...

I've read and tried some post about dividing values in here but I can't still solve the problem.

This is the snippet :

```
$query2 = "SELECT SUM(jumlah_poin) AS jumlah_mk FROM tbl_nilai WHERE nama_mk = 'Pengantar Teknologi Informasi' 
AND nip_dsn = '198'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);

$query4 = "SELECT count(1) FROM tbl_nilai WHERE nama_mk = 'Pengantar Teknologi Informasi' 
AND nip_dsn = '198'";
$result4 = mysql_query($query4);
$row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4);

$sum ['jumlah2']= $row2 ['jumlah_mk'] / $row4 [0];

echo json_encode(array($resultArray,$sum));
```

and I need to make it in one `echo`. Any explanation you can provide to a newb will be appreciated. help and teach me please :D

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are no longer supported by PHP. Try using `mysqli_*` or PDO. Better use prepared statements while you are learning, it may save you from lots of problems later. Also validate everything you read/get. [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons, try one of this:

1. Change query to

   ```
   $query4 = "SELECT count(1) as totalCount FROM tbl_nilai WHERE nama_mk ='Pengantar Teknologi Informasi' AND nip_dsn = '198'";
   ```

   and

   ```
   $sum ['jumlah2']= $row2 ['jumlah_mk'] / $row4 ['totalCount'];
   ```
2. Your 2nd query returns count as 0, if no record match.

Comment: it still show "false", so i try to do this : 
`$div = $row2 / $row4;`

`$sum ['jumlah2']= $div ['nilai'];`

and the result is "Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in..." :(

Comment: when i do this `$sum ['jumlah2']= $row2 ['jumlah_mk']` and `$sum ['jumlah3']= $row4['totalCount'];`, it shows "jumlah2":"910" and "jumlah3":"8". then i try to do this `$sum ['jumlah2']= $row2 ['jumlah_mk']/8;`and the result is "jumlah2":113.75 (the correct answer)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the devide by zero error I might put it in an if statement

```
if( $row4[0] != 0 ) { // any falsy value would evaluate to zero
    $sum ['jumlah2']= $row2 ['jumlah_mk'] / $row4 [0];
} else {
    $sum = $sum_default_value;
}
```